# Which tables were affected during single query run by triggers cascade

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

According to [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/05/07/mysql-audit-plugin-now-available-in-percona-server-5-5-and-5-6/), the new Percona Servers, announced yesterday (May 6), both include the open source version of the MySQL Audit Plugin.

The task I want to accomplish is: log the tables affected by cascade trigger execution during one single update query run. E. g. when `UPDATE MY_TABLE …` is executed, the triggers `{BEFORE,AFTER}_UPDATE` may update other tables, on which there might be their own triggers, etc.

Currently I use the domestic solution; inside *all* triggers I put smth like:

```
IF (
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM  `information_schema`.`ROUTINES` 
        WHERE  specific_name = 'my_own_log' 
          AND  routine_schema = 'my_schema'
) > 0 THEN
    CALL my_own_log ('FOO_TRIGGER', 'Hi, I’m to update MY_TABLE') ;
END IF ;
```

In production I don’t have the `my_own_log` procedure defined and since the `information_schema` table is well-optimized, I don’t yield any performance penalties.

The question is if I could switch to enterprise solution (aforementioned `audit` plugin) to harvest an information about *which tables were affected by cascade trigger execution*. JFYI: the only similar question I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421404/find-out-which-tables-were-affected-by-triggers) is not supplied with an applicable answer.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin auditing is designed to register outside interactions with the server, being used to track invasion and other related activities, not interactions of the server with itself (like triggers and procedures).

These internal activities will not generate actions on any audit plugin by design. From the dev blog:

---

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/audit-log-plugin-logging-control.html

The MySQL server calls the audit log plugin to write an  element whenever an auditable event occurs, such as when it completes execution of an SQL statement received from a client. Typically the first  element written after server startup has the server description and startup options. Elements following that one represent events such as client connect and disconnect events, executed SQL statements, and so forth. **Only top-level statements are logged, not statements within stored programs such as triggers or stored procedures.** Contents of files referenced by statements such as LOAD DATA INFILE are not logged.

---

For now, you are better with your homegrown solution. You could try to improve its performance so you can turn it on in the production environment.

Comment: Maybe these wheels were not invented yet. Your requirement is very unusual. 
You see, given that triggers,FKs are already there, you should be able to tell the actions of any query before executing it, just by static analysis, unless you use some kind of probabilistic route of action to define your outcomes.
So it is very unusual to not know beforehand where your DML statements will act.